# DOM usage in QTP

Tags: dom, qtp

During script execution a pop up won't go away, and it happens only through QTP(v12.02).

I am trying DOM to bypass the problem, the pop up event was on selection of a drop down value, so I used some code to find the correct index and use DOM to select the value

Browser().Page().WebList().Object.selectedIndex = itmindx

With this the pop up issue got resolved, but now to complete the process,I need to click the Save button which is disabled as the page didn't refreshed when  the value was selected ( tried refreshing through QTP, tab out etc--didn't worked as it loads the previous value).So I used the fire event method

Browser().Page().WebList().Fireevent "onchange"

with this I ran in to the same issue of multiple pop ups. Used the following

Browser().Page().WebList().Object.onchange()

but then QTP won't executes the next line unless I hit enter externally on the pop up(multiple pop up is resovled but now QTP is stuck. I don't want to use RS.... Any solutions?

Comment: Why don't you use WebList.Select to select the WebList item? That should work. It will work in 99% of all cases if you (temporarily, for the duration of the .Select call) set the Web replay mode to "mouse" (default is "event"). That the WebButton is not enabled indicates that the direct manipulation of .Object.selectedIndex bypasses the event handling of the app, yielding an inconsistent GUI state, so that option is a dead-end imho.

Comment: Well by using QTP methods/descriptive programming the pop up appears more than once and does not goes away by clicking Ok , and it only happens through QTP, manually the system works fine.

Comment: Did you try with WebList.Select with Web replay mode = "mouse"? What exactly were the results? What does that script then look like? What exactly are you doing manually, and what is in the script that mirrors those manual actions?

Comment: It generated the pop up more than once, which is exactly what I don't want. It's suppose to come once, and when someone manually logs into the application it appears only once. Even the traditional select methods are working but some how all of these methods are firing the onchnage event twice.

Comment: See web event config docs in QTP documentation, and show your fire event code. QTP generates the wrong events.

Comment: Do you think adding an event listener (by running a js) will help?. I tried doing it though but the element does not have a unique id. I can do some more research on that, but only if adding a listener is an effective option.

Comment: No :-& i don't, sorry

Answer (score 1):

To enable the button

`Browser().Page().WebButton().Object.disabled = false`

Or

To hit enter for the popup

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}")`

[ http://ss64.com/vb/sendkeys.html ]

Go for hitting the Enter button using SendKeys. It is not a good idea accessing DOM and change the state ourselves. There is a chance that you might miss potential defects!

Comment: I don't want to access the button directly, but to initiate the on change event so that the page can reload and tell if there's an error with the combination of values selected and hence enabling the button (if everything is good).The onchange event  calls a function which pops a alert and then formats some values before submission. While executing I noticed that only after hitting enter, the other values gets formatted which shows that the HTML code is waiting for a response for the alert message and won't process further and hence QTP is stuck on the same line.

Comment: and I just started exploring QTP with DOM , so can you tell me if this is a normal behavior with an ALERT in the piece of HTML code we trying to access?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot - which alert we are talking about here? ALERT is  coming from the browser, rt? not from QTP?

Comment: Yes Alert is coming from the browser not from QTP. If I execute the onchange event it contains a function which had an alert and I am talking purely about the html code.See below--  function changeStatusEvent()
 {

 // 
    if ( document.SFAgreementDtls.status.value == '1' )
   alert( Are you sure you want to do this?');

Comment: Then `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SendKeys("{ENTER}")` add this line in QTP to hit 'ok' button

Comment: It won't work as QTP is stuck on the line which executes the fire event!      i.e. Browser().Page().WebList().Object.onchange()